# Start question numbering at 47 instead of 00

Tags: xslt-2.0

How do I get the questions to number starting at 47 and not 00. I need the first number to be mc15q6647. This script below is giving me mc15q6601.

```
<xsl:when test="count(preceding::xhtml:li[@property = 'ktp:question']) + 1 &lt; 50">
    mc15q6647
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(count(preceding::xhtml:li[@property = 'ktp:question']) + 1, '00')" />
</xsl:when>
```

Comment: Wouldn’t you just do ` + 47` instead of ` + 1`?

Comment: Yup, that worked! Thanks! I had a feeling it was something simple. :)